# $.fn.func do not return me string

Tags: jquery

this function is work but when call that value of return is undifined

```
            $.fn.check=function (fieldName,fieldValue) {
        $val=$(this).val();
        $.post('proccess.php',{check:'check',fieldName:fieldName,fieldValue:fieldValue},
function (res) {
            if(res=='true')
            {
                return 'true'; // this line is work
            }
            else if(res=='false')
            {
                return 'false';  // this line is work
            }
        })
    };

    //calling function
    $('#register input[name=name]').focusout(
        function () {
            var checked=$(this).check('name',$(this).val());
            //but here  value of checked is undifined
            if(checked==true)
            {
                $(this).next('.checked').text('ok');
            }
            else if(checked==false)
            {
                $(this).next('.checked').text('not ok');
            }
        }
    )
```

my problem is with $.fn. function  dont return string data 
my country language is not english please dont dislike my post :(

Comment: that is not same problem that topic is different and cant resolve my problem

Comment: try this:-https://eval.in/997579

Comment: @yas17 It is the exact same problem, you're trying to return something from an asynchronous callback